# Why onComplete function is executed many times?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Here is an example to reproduce the issue.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var repeatedTimes = 0;
        $.colorbox({html:'hello1'});
        $.colorbox({html:'hello2'});
        $.colorbox({html:'hello3'});
        $.colorbox(
        {
            html:'hello4',
            onComplete: function() {
                alert("repeat " + repeatedTimes++ + " times.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why is onComplete function executed multiples times?

NOTE: This code is only for reproduce the issue. In real scenery, between colorbox calls, other code are executed.

NOTE: In this case, colorbox is used to display messages between usually long time processes. Problems are when these process are shorts.

Answer (score 0):

i am not familar with this module, but you should try to call plugins on specifix elements, not just $.

Try $('html').colorbox, whatever it is...

Comment: In colorbox documentation said:
// Called directly with HTML
$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});

Comment: `$.colobox()` is indeed the intended usage of this plugin.  And of course the way you mentioned here, also. But there really are plenty of plugins - not to mention built in functions ($.ajax, $.post) - that are called in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As Gummy pointed out, you will never have a need to call colorbox in this way.  Anywhere you have the `$.colorbox()`, the colorbox is opened right away (even if you set the `open:false` option).  Although you don't see the first 3 calls because the control of the visible part is immediately taken by the next call, they still run their full course.  That also means that had you defined the `onLoad`, `onOpen`, and `onCleanup` callbacks, they would have been called 4 times as well.  Because it happens so fast, by the time `onComplete` runs for all 4 calls, the settings are now whatever is in the last call.

If, however, each one were executed after the last one completed its execution, then you wouldn't see this happen.  For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var repeatedTimes = 0;

    $.colorbox({html:'hello1'});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.colorbox({html:'hello2'});
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.colorbox({html:'hello3'});
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.colorbox({
            html:'hello4',
            onComplete: function() {
                alert("repeat " + repeatedTimes++ + " times.");
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

works the way you expect - or rather, only calls onComplete once.  I suppose you could use this as some sort of banner or something, but there's better ways to do that sort of thing.